# JVM cannot use 8 CPUon Linux

Tags: jvm, cpu, cpu-usage

I have observed that JVM cannot user 8 CPU advantage. Because when a thread runs more than 1 secs, other threds are waiting for it. there is no lock beetween these threds is there any jvm option for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The JVM should have no internal locks that inhibit scaling like this.  There are many benchmarks (specifically SPECjbb2000 and SPECjbb2005) that show single JVMs scaling to a great number of cores.  I would say that you ARE somehow locking between threads, even if you don't know how.

You don't list your JVM level, vendor, or OS.  Additionally, the evidence showing lack of scaling would be good.  All of those would be necessary to answer the question.